Dynamically Set Table Names in SQL
Is there a way to dynamically set table names in SQL?
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temptable
CREATE TABLE #temptable ([Rownum] INT IDENTITY(1, 1), [DatabaseName] INT, [CustomerName] NVARCHAR(50) )

INSERT INTO #temptable ([DatabaseName], [CustomerName])
VALUES
( 361, 'Adam' ),
( 362, 'Bella' ),
( 363, 'Charlie' )

So the output would be
SELECT * FROM C361.dbo.CustomerInfo WHERE CustomerName = 'Adam'
SELECT * FROM C362.dbo.CustomerInfo WHERE CustomerName = 'Bella'
SELECT * FROM C363.dbo.CustomerInfo WHERE CustomerName = 'Charlie'


Do you want to just generate the instructions as string or actually run them?

Redesign your tables so that you don't need to? Almost always when this requirement exists it is because of a bad design decision.

Also the table name in your queries is the same in each one. It's the database name that differs. In that case, you should be connecting to the correct database in the application and not use 3 part naming in your queries. Then you can use an identical query for every database.

Sorry I was trying to reply yesterday but somehow got the perpetual spinning thing. Charlieface answered my question below.

You can create a dynamic SQL string using STRING_AGG.
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql =
  STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), CONCAT('
SELECT *
FROM ', QUOTENAME(CONCAT('C', tt.DatabaseName)), '.dbo.CustomerInfo
WHERE CustomerName = ', QUOTENAME(tt.CustomerName, '''')
  )), '')
FROM #temptable tt;

PRINT @sql;   -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

Note the use of QUOTENAME to correctly escape names and values.
